# easiest way to display xml tree structure in aspx

Tags: asp.net, xml

I need the easiest way to display xml tree structure in aspx - nothing fancy!

this is my xml - which i am reading from a file on the hdd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>

<citizenvitalsign>
  <citizenid>v56456</citizenid>
  <logopendate>2011-05-05</logopendate>
  <logexpiredate>2011-05-20</logexpiredate>
  <vitalsigns>
    <vitalsigndate>2011-05-04</vitalsigndate>
    <vitalsignstime>12:34:23</vitalsignstime>
    <signs>
      <oximeter>
        <saturationlevel>56</saturationlevel>
        <heartrate>84</heartrate>
      </oximeter>
      <weigth>
        <weigthingrams>75100</weigthingrams>
      </weigth>
      <ecg>
        <ecgvalues>
          <value>0.00432</value>
          <value>0.00532</value>
          <value>0.00832</value>
          <value>0.00432</value>
          <value>0.00532</value>
          <value>0.00832</value>
        </ecgvalues>
      </ecg>
      <bloodpressure>
        <systolic>78</systolic>
        <diastolic>123</diastolic>
        <heartrate>89</heartrate>
      </bloodpressure>
    </signs>
  </vitalsigns>
  <vitalsigns>
    <vitalsigndate>2011-05-05</vitalsigndate>
    <vitalsignstime>10:35:23</vitalsignstime>
    <signs>
      <oximeter>
        <saturationlevel>56</saturationlevel>
        <heartrate>84</heartrate>
      </oximeter>
      <ecg>
        <ecgvalues>
          <value>0.004456</value>
          <value>0.00532</value>
          <value>0.000434</value>
          <value>0.00489</value>
          <value>0.005122</value>
          <value>0.008122</value>
        </ecgvalues>
      </ecg>
      <bloodpressure>
        <systolic>85</systolic>
        <diastolic>111</diastolic>
        <heartrate>90</heartrate>
      </bloodpressure>
    </signs>
  </vitalsigns>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the whole contents of the `aspx` is the XML content:

Just output a `application/xml` (or `text/xml`, though see the link in the comment by @jasso first) content type header with your XML and let the browser show the XML in the native way.

Most browsers already show XML in a tree structure natively.

---

If you want to output it as part of the page output, with other content, I would pass the XML through an [XML pretty printer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Pretty_Printer) and then HTML encode it for output.

Comment: Using `text/xml` is controversial. You should always sent also a charset header when using content type `text/xml` since otherwise an RFC compliant client [MUST assume the charset is "us-ascii"](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3023#section-8.5) regardless of the encoding value in XML declaration. See also [W3C's view](http://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/#xml-media-types) on media types for XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Literal` control along with `Server.HtmlEncode` to show the xml.

Example here: [Display XML on an ASP.NET page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914143/display-xml-on-an-asp-net-page)